# Module parse failed: Unexpected token (xx.xx) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type react js

Tags: npm, webpack

I am developing the front end of a web-app using reactjs. Unfortunately I get an error when I run `webpack --config webpack.dev.js` on my project.

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 13:17
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (13:17)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.
| let root_dashboard = document.getElementById('root_dashboard_app')
> const element = (<App />)
| if (root_dashboard !== null) {
|     ReactDOM.render(
webpack 5.72.0
```

The app was working fine before I upgraded to webpack 5.72.0 and react 17.0.2

I have tried the solutions proposed:

[Module parse failed: Unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52268320/module-parse-failed-unexpected-token)

[React - Module parse failed: Unexpected Token. You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63769414/react-module-parse-failed-unexpected-token-you-may-need-an-appropriate-loade)

[React build issus :You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62058630/react-build-issus-you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type)

and ohters, but non of them work for my case

Here are the files involved:

**index.js**

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
let root_dashboard = document.getElementById('root_dashboard_app')
const element = (<App />)
if (root_dashboard !== null) { ReactDOM.render(element,root_dashboard)}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{"presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-react",
        {   "runtime": "automatic",
            "importSource": "@emotion/core"},
        "@babel/preset-env",
        [   "es2015",
            "stage-0",
            "react"
        ]
    ]
],
"plugins": ["@emotion/babel-plugin",[
        "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx",{
            "runtime": "automatic" }
        ]
    ]
}
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = 
{
    presets: [["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"]],
    plugins: ["@emotion/babel-plugin",["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx", {"runtime": "automatic"}]]
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const WorkboxWebpackPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production';
const stylesHandler = MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader;
var webpack = require('webpack');

const config = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
        filename: 'bundle_frontend_codes.js'
    },
    resolve: {extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']},
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: 'index.html',}),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({filename: "all.css"}),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({"React": "react",}),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$|jsx/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            include: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
            ],
        query: {
            presets: ["es2015", "react"]
        },
        use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: [
                    '@babel/preset-env', 
                    '@babel/preset-react'
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [stylesHandler, 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
    },
    {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|png|jpg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset',
    },],},
    externals: {
        'react': 'React',
        'react-native': true,
    },
};

module.exports = () => {
    if (isProduction) {
        config.mode = 'production';
        config.plugins.push(new WorkboxWebpackPlugin.GenerateSW());
    } else { 
        config.mode = 'development';
    }
    return config;
};
```

**webpack.dev.js**

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.config.js');
module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
});
```

**App.jsx**

```
...
render(){
    ...
    return(<div>My App</div>)
}
```

Help is much appreciated !

Comment: have you solve it?

Comment: no, sorry. I am using old versions of webpack and react.